# Is it possible to get multi-user support on Android with help from the boot manager?

Tags: bootloader, multi-user

I know that a common problem with Android tablets is that [they lack](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6693/support-for-multiple-users-on-same-device) [multi-user support.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15030) I wonder if there isn't already a solution that allows me to select the user on boot by linking/moving/changing the data partition.

**There are boot managers that allow the selection of the (custom) ROM to be loaded, just like Windows/Linux dual-boot. Are there any Apps that allows me to select the data partition/user on boot? Or let me switch the user data on-the-fly without rebooting?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [SwitchMe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fahrbot.apps.switchme) if you have root, which I believe does all you ask

Comment: While SwitchMe does not act as boot manager, does the job very well.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know exactly if you are satisfied with this, but in the near future VmWare will release one version for Android. 
This adds a little bit of multi user support, because you can start another android system like any other apps. 
Video Link to a little demonstration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HRSilifLYT4

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but this is my best answer:

You could have a system where you mount an sdcard partiton as data etc for the other user, unfortunately, there is no project in development for this THAT I KNOW OF.

However, this would work, unfortunately, you would need to reboot, so it isn't really what you wanted.

Comment: data2sd can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Titanium Backup has a 'multi user data profiles' feature that can be used to have a per app multi user like functionality: It has some restrictions like 'doesnt work with apps that have services', etc.

http://www.titaniumtrack.com/kb/titanium-backup-kb/titanium-backup-howtos.html#multi-user-data-profiles