# Creating multiple user accounts on the same terminal with Android 4.4.2

Tags: accounts, multi-user

I need to create different user accounts on the same Android phone.
Is it possible to do that with the Samsung Galaxy note 3 with Android 4.4.2. If yes how can you do that ?

Comment: multiple user accounts on Android itself

Comment: Related - [Separate user accounts on one Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65829/separate-user-accounts-on-one-android-device).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Support for Multiple Users on same device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6693/support-for-multiple-users-on-same-device)