# I want to install 2 WhatsApp accounts in my mi4 mobile

Tags: applications

I want to install 2 WhatsApp accounts in one phone, iam using mi4 mobile phone, so please let me know the procedure and settings which should be used for the process

Comment: Please also see [Separate user accounts on one Android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/65829/16575): if your device runs Android 5+, you can simply take different user accounts for that (as [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/112959/16575) states).

Answer (score 0):

There are many apps available on play store that help you install 2 whatsapp on a single android phone. You can try **parallel space** app from play store.