# How to use multiple whatsapp, paytm, hike and more accounts in an Android phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, multi-user

How to use multiple whatsapp, paytm, hike and more accounts in an Android phone? Or any other android app which uses authenticated single user login apps.

Comment: Same thing: [Support for Multiple Users on same device](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/6693)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can login with another user, by adding multiple user in your Android device. We can Enable Multiple User Accounts on Android 4.2 and Above.

1. Create another User Account by opening the notification by `double pulldown notification` to get the `other quick settings`.
2. In that other quick settings, on top-right corner you'll find a round icon. That is Admin user icon(if you're using it for first time).
3. Click on it and create a `new user`(it'll remain until you delete it) or use a `guest user`(it'll be deleted after using it, but you can also keep it).
4. After creating `new/guest user`. Just go to `Google Play Store`, install whatever app you want. Don't worry it'll use your existing same app files but not users data, so it won't download a new one.
5. You can login those apps with another id. Like this you can use Whatsapp, hike, facebook, twitter, paytm and more...
6. Before that, go to `more settings` Click and open that created new/guest user's settings and enable `Allow phone calls and SMS`. So that you'll get verification SMS or call.

If any help you can comment it, i'll keep on updating it if any change or improvement.